# Debugging Triple Fault

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, interrupt-handling, osdev

I'm trying an [operating system development tutorial](http://wyoos.org) (wyoos.org) and I'm having trouble getting interrupts to work. When I try to run my OS in Virtualbox, I get a triple fault, sometime after activating interrupts. I have learned that this is probably because my global descriptor table is not being set up correctly. It may be likely that I'm trying to jump into a data block.

I'm pretty sure this is happening when an interrupt is being fired and I'm not handling it, but I'm having a hard time debugging it. Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

My interrupt handling consists of three files, `interruptstubs.s`, `interrupts.h` and `interrupts.cpp`

```
#interruptstubs.s

.set IRQ_BASE, 0x20

.section .text
.extern _ZN16InterruptManager15HandleInterruptEhj
.global _ZN16IterruptManager26IgnoreInterruptRequestEv

.macro HandleException num
.global _ZN16InterruptManager16HandleException\num\()Ev
_ZN16InterruptManager16handleException\num\()Ev:
    movb $\num, (interruptnumber)
    jmp int_bottom
.endm

.macro HandleInterruptRequest num
.global _ZN16InterruptManager26HandleInterruptRequest\num\()Ev
_ZN16InterruptManager26handleInterruptRequest\num\()Ev:
    movb $\num + IRQ_BASE, (interruptnumber)
    jmp int_bottom
.endm

HandleInterruptRequest 0x00
HandleInterruptRequest 0x01

int_bottom:

  pusha
  pushl %ds
  pushl %es
  pushl %fs
  pushl %gs

  pushl %esp
  push (interruptnumber)
  call  _ZN16InterruptManager15HandleInterruptEhj
  # addl $5, %esp
  movl %eax, %esp

  popl %gs
  popl %fs
  popl %es
  popl %ds
  popa

_ZN16IterruptManager26IgnoreInterruptRequestEv:
  iret

  .data
interruptnumber:   .byte 0
```

interrupts.h

```
#ifndef __INTERRUPTS_H
#define __INTERRUPTS_H

#include "types.h"
#include "port.h"
#include "gdt.h"

class InterruptManager {
 public:
  InterruptManager(GlobalDescriptorTable* gdt);
  ~InterruptManager();

  static void Activate();

  static uint32_t HandleInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint32_t esp );

  static void InterruptIgnore();
  static void HandleInterruptRequest();
  static void HandleInterruptRequest0x00();
  static void HandleInterruptRequest0x01();

 protected:
  struct GateDescriptor {
    uint16_t handlerAddressLowBits;
    uint16_t gdt_codeSegmentSelector;
    uint8_t reserved;
    uint8_t access_rights;
    uint16_t handlerAddressHighBits;
  } __attribute__((packed));

  static GateDescriptor interruptDescriptorTable[256];

  struct InterruptDescriptorTablePointer
  {
    uint16_t size;
    uint32_t base;
  } __attribute__((packed));

  static void SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(
                                               uint8_t interruptNumber,
                                               uint16_t codeSegmentSelectorOffset,
                                               void (*handler)(),
                                               uint8_t DescriptorPrivilegeLevel,
                                               uint8_t DescriptorType);

  Port8BitSlow picMasterCommand;
  Port8BitSlow picMasterData;
  Port8BitSlow picWorkerCommand;
  Port8BitSlow picWorkerData;

};

#endif
```

interrupts.cpp

```
#ifndef __INTERRUPTS_H
#define __INTERRUPTS_H

#include "types.h"
#include "port.h"
#include "gdt.h"

class InterruptManager {
 public:
  InterruptManager(GlobalDescriptorTable* gdt);
  ~InterruptManager();

  static void Activate();

  static uint32_t HandleInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint32_t esp );

  static void InterruptIgnore();
  static void HandleInterruptRequest();
  static void HandleInterruptRequest0x00();
  static void HandleInterruptRequest0x01();

 protected:
  struct GateDescriptor {
    uint16_t handlerAddressLowBits;
    uint16_t gdt_codeSegmentSelector;
    uint8_t reserved;
    uint8_t access_rights;
    uint16_t handlerAddressHighBits;
  } __attribute__((packed));

  static GateDescriptor interruptDescriptorTable[256];

  struct InterruptDescriptorTablePointer
  {
    uint16_t size;
    uint32_t base;
  } __attribute__((packed));

  static void SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(
                                               uint8_t interruptNumber,
                                               uint16_t codeSegmentSelectorOffset,
                                               void (*handler)(),
                                               uint8_t DescriptorPrivilegeLevel,
                                               uint8_t DescriptorType);

  Port8BitSlow picMasterCommand;
  Port8BitSlow picMasterData;
  Port8BitSlow picWorkerCommand;
  Port8BitSlow picWorkerData;

};

#endif
(v2_ordergroove-py27) ~/s/wyoos ❯❯❯ cat interrupts.cpp
#include "interrupts.h"

void printf(const char* str);

InterruptManager::GateDescriptor InterruptManager::interruptDescriptorTable[256];

void InterruptManager::SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(
        uint8_t interruptNumber,
        uint16_t codeSegmentSelectorOffset,
        void (*handler)(),
        uint8_t DescriptorPrivilegeLevel,
        uint8_t descriptorType)
{
  printf("\nGDT Entry Start\n");
  interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].handlerAddressLowBits = ((uint32_t)handler) & 0xFFFF;
  interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].handlerAddressHighBits = (((uint32_t)handler) >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
  interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].gdt_codeSegmentSelector = codeSegmentSelectorOffset;

  const uint8_t IDT_DESC_PRESENT = 0x00;
  interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].access_rights = IDT_DESC_PRESENT | descriptorType | (DescriptorPrivilegeLevel << 5);
  interruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].reserved = 0;
  printf("\nGDT Entry End\n");
}

InterruptManager::InterruptManager(GlobalDescriptorTable* gdt)
  : picMasterCommand(0x20),
    picMasterData(0x21),
    picWorkerCommand(0xA0),
    picWorkerData(0xA1)
{
  uint16_t CodeSegment = gdt->CodeSegmentSelector();
  const uint8_t IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE = 0xE;

  for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(i, CodeSegment, &InterruptIgnore, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);
  }
  SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x20, CodeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x00, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);
  SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x21, CodeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x01, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);

  picMasterCommand.Write(0x11);
  picWorkerCommand.Write(0x11);

  picMasterData.Write(0x20);
  picWorkerData.Write(0x20);

  picMasterData.Write(0x04);
  picWorkerData.Write(0x02);

  picMasterData.Write(0x01);
  picWorkerData.Write(0x01);

  picMasterData.Write(0x00);
  picWorkerData.Write(0x00);

  InterruptDescriptorTablePointer idt;
  idt.size = 256 * sizeof(GateDescriptor) - 1;
  idt.base = (uint32_t)interruptDescriptorTable;
  asm volatile("lidt %0" : : "m" (idt));
}

void InterruptManager::InterruptIgnore() {

}

void InterruptManager::HandleInterruptRequest0x01() {
 printf("Handle 0x01"); 
}

void InterruptManager::HandleInterruptRequest0x00() {
 printf("Handle 0x00"); 
}

InterruptManager::~InterruptManager()
{
}


void InterruptManager::Activate()
{
  printf("\nStart activate\n");
  asm("sti");
  printf("Done activate\n");
}

uint32_t InterruptManager::HandleInterrupt(uint8_t interrupt, uint32_t esp)
{
  printf("start handle interrupt");
  //const char* debugString = " INTERRUPT";
  char* foo = "INTERRUPT 0x00";
  char* hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  foo[12] = hex[(interrupt >> 4) & 0xF];
  foo[13] = hex[interrupt & 0xF];
  printf(foo);

  return esp;
}
```

My full source code is available at https://github.com/munk/wyoos/tree/gdt-triple-fault

Comment: Use better tools. For example, bochs is known to provide useful information.

Comment: Do you see the message "Start activate"? Do you see "Done activate"?

Comment: I have a few suggestions: 1) You should set up a proper handler for all vectors. Most of the vectors go to InterruptIgnore, which doesn't print a message or even do an iret, so it's guaranteed to crash without warning if it gets there. If you at least put a message into InterruptIgnore, you can see if it is getting there.

Comment: 2) It looks like there are two different implementations of InterruptManager::HandleInterruptRequest0x00, one in assembly, and one in C++. The one written in assembly is the correct one, but the one written in C++ is the one being put into the interrupt table.

Comment: 3) I didn't check the details of the code to fill in the IDT. I suggest dumping the raw bytes of the IDT after it is set up, to make sure it is filled in the way you expect. (You don't have to dump the whole thing; a few selected entries should be sufficient.)

Comment: 4) Using a global variable in the interrupt handler seems dangerous. I don't see any specific problem with it, though.

5) It sets the interrupt base for both the master and slave PICs to 0x20.

Comment: @prl I do see both start and done activate.

Comment: Quickly glancing at this. You set the default interrupt handler to `&InterruptIgnore` but that is a _C++_ function that is a regular function that does `ret` to end. You need something that does an `iret`. You could put such a function in your interrupt stubs assembly file.

Comment: This line is wrong `const uint8_t IDT_DESC_PRESENT = 0x00;`. It should be `const uint8_t IDT_DESC_PRESENT = 0x80;`

Comment: In fact all your interrupt handlers are being routed into C++ functions (Handler00, 01 etc). They should be directed into the stubs in your assembly file that are designed to work as interrupts. Your assembly stubs ends with `iret`, but C++ functions end with `ret`. You can't use `ret` to return from an interrupt handler.

Comment: @prl : The global should be safe in this context (non-Mullticore) as interrupt gates will disable interrupts upon entry and the global is pushed on the stack before the _C++_ code is run so should be safe even if the C++ code enables interrupts

Comment: There are some issues and bugs in the WYOOS code you may wish to look at. I wrote an answer this week on [OSDEV](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) about a GDT issues (that can affect interrupts), problems if you want to access memory beyond 64MB (like the linear frame buffer etc), issues with exceptions that have hardware push an error code and those that don't. I have some bug fix suggestions: https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32874 . Although the WYOOS tutorial is one of the better ones it does have some issues.

Comment: @MichaelPetch changing IDT_DESC_PRESENT to the correct value fixed the problem, it was a typo on my part :/ I've voted to close because of this, but this comment thread is super valuable, thank you!

Comment: @munk, Indeed this is a valuable thread. I am also following this tutorial series and I was able to understand how to debug stuff from this thread.